# Dock shows on only one screen on OS X Mavericks

Tags: dock, macos

I understood that every display would behave independently on OS X Mavericks, and that it would get its own bar (top of the screen) and dock.

However, the dock shows only on the main screen, and not on the other screen, is it normal?

Comment: IF you check this in Windows, it does have one bar either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using a stacked display configuration, as in main monitor with the secondary above, then the dock does not appear on the second display. If it can or does, I'd like to know because this is how I run my setup.

If you have them oriented right to left, then the dock will appear. In my limited experience, only one image of the dock appears at a time on whichever monitor you activate it on. You have to play with it, as the cursor motion seems to need to be elongated or dramatic or whatever. Not a big thing, just different.

It's there by default, trust me. HTH.

Comment: I have them from right to left, and the dock only shows on the right (even if I'm working on the left monitor). I haven't restarted since the install yesterday, maybe it's just a bug that will go away, i'll try that tonight.

Comment: It seems there are some bugs :( After restarting, the dock started showing up on all monitors like it should, but after waking up from sleep, the dock only shows on the main monitor.

Comment: Update on the bugs: sometimes, the dock seems to be "locked" on one screen: on screen 2, I can't show it. I have to show it on screen 1, and then the dock will properly show on both screen. It is random, not related to restarting, and affect both monitors randomly. Maybe it's a sideeffect of an app like TotalSpaces…

Comment: This just happened to me, I found that opening display preferences, changing the alignment and then changing it back fixed the problem for me.

Comment: The dock will never leave the primary display if you have unchecked `Displays have separate Spaces` in `System Preferences` -> `Mission Control`.

Comment: To get the dock to switch displays, move the mouse pointer to the bottom of the display you want it to move to, then move the pointer further down below the bottom of that display.

Answer (score 7):

None of this works if you use a left or right positioned dock in Mavericks.  The dock will ONLY migrate with a Bottom mounted dock and ONLY if the monitor positions are set side-by-side (corner or top/bottom mounted will not work, at least as of 10.9.1 and 10.9.2 versions of OS X). Apparently, people who prefer left/right positioned docks (to maximize vertical space without hiding since most monitors are now wider than tall) are now second class citizens.  The now semi-opaque color is also much brighter for such left/right docks as well, which many seem to hate).

Answer (score 4):

The dock only shows on one display at a time. It is hidden on all other displays, but can be made visible just as you would any hidden dock. That is, moving your mouse cursor below the display you would like the dock to appear (or left/right depending on where your dock normally is). Then the dock will hide on it's current display and appear on that display.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this link:

http://rwillgo.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/mac-os-x-mavericks-how-to-move-the-dock-from-one-display-to-another/

The gist of it is that you have to tap + hold + drag the mouse to the bottom of the screen for the dock to move.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is nothing to do with which screen is active, and more to do with a "safety feature" that prevents the Dock from popping up too easily.

To get the dock to appear on another screen (active or inactive), you need to move the mouse pointer to the bottom of the screen and keep moving past the bottom edge until the dock appears.

Leaving the pointer at the bottom edge of the screen will not work.

With a Magic Trackpad,  it's a bit more fiddly - you can either take one giant fast swipe down past the bottom edge, or swipe down several times (about 4) in quick succession after the pointer has already hit the bottom of the screen.

And, once again, you do not need to click on the screen to make it active before the Dock will appear.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the dock switch from one screen to the other, you should "jump" with the mouse on the bottom of the screen you want it to be shown on.

Here it is shown more: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5891?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US (look for "Working with the Dock")

Answer (score 0):

To bring the dock over to a different display:

If you've clicked on a display to make it active, note how the Menu Bar brightens. But you don't need to.
Without clicking the mouse again, move the cursor all the way down to the bottom of the screen. This is the same technique as if you had invoked System Preferences > Dock > "Automatically hide and show the Dock."
When the cursor touches the bottom, the Dock will rise up from the bottom and stay there on the selected display. (If you had previously enabled "Automatically hide and show the Dock," it will disappear as you move the mouse upwards, but remain tied to that display.)
To move the Dock back to the main display (or any other display), repeat the process starting with Step #1.

Answer (score 0):

exactly correct. move the cursor to the next screen, all the way to the bottom and then keep scrolling as if to move it beyond the bottom for a second and the dock will appear. It does not do this if you just tap the bottom of the screen with the cursor, bouncing it off of the bottom so to speak, apparently because this may be an unintentional mouse movement. with a little practice, this becomes second nature.

Answer (score -1):

It worked fine [here](http://rwillgo.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/mac-os-x-mavericks-how-to-move-the-dock-from-one-display-to-another/):

> Moving the dock to a second display is not straightforward but it’s easy to do. Assuming you are using an Apple Magic Mouse, you can tell OS X to move the dock to the active display by following these steps:
>
> First, click the desktop or any window on the display where you want the dock to move to. This will make the menu bar go active.
>
> Then, place your finger on the mouse while moving the cursor towards the bottom of the screen. The dock will them pop up.